# How to use Ant Design DatePicker inside Ant Design Editable Table?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant Design Editable Table where there is an `operation` column where there is an `edit` button. I have 2 other columns which are `date` and `value`. So what I want to have is when I press on the edit button for a specific row, I want to be able to change the `date` using `<DatePicker />` component from Ant Design. I have not been able to find a solution anywhere online for me. What I have right now is:

**EditableTable.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Table, Form, Button, DatePicker } from "antd";

import EditableCell from "./EditableCell";

const OtherLocsTable = ({ data, setData }) => {
   const [form] = Form.useForm();
   const [editingKey, setEditingKey] = useState("");
   const isEditing = (record) => record.key === editingKey;
   const edit = (record) => {
      form.setFieldsValue({
         date: "",
         measurement: "",
         ...record,
      });
      setEditingKey(record.key);
   };
  const save = async (key) => {
    try {
      const row = await form.validateFields();
      const newData = [...data];
      const index = newData.findIndex((item) => key === item.key);

      if (index > -1) {
        const item = newData[index];
        newData.splice(index, 1, { ...item, ...row });
        setData(newData);
        setEditingKey("");
      } else {
        newData.push(row);
        setData(newData);
        setEditingKey("");
      }
    } catch (errInfo) {
      console.log("Validate Failed:", errInfo);
    }
  };
const columns = [
    {
      title: "Date",
      dataIndex: "date",
      key: "date",
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      title: "Measurement",
      dataIndex: "measurement",
      key: "measurement",
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      title: "Operation",
      dataIndex: "operation",
      render: (_, record) => {
        const editable = isEditing(record);
        const lastElement = [...data].pop();

        return editable ? (
          <span>
            <a
              href="javascript:;"
              onClick={() => save(record.key)}
              style={{
                marginRight: 8,
              }}
            >
              Save
            </a>
            <Popconfirm title="Sure to cancel?" onConfirm={cancel}>
              <a>Cancel</a>
            </Popconfirm>
          </span>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Typography.Link
              disabled={editingKey !== ""}
              onClick={() => edit(record)}
            >
              Edit
            </Typography.Link>
            {data.length > 1 ? (
              record.key === lastElement.key ? (
                <Typography.Link
                  type="danger"
                  disabled={editingKey !== ""}
                  onClick={() => deleteRow(record)}
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: 15,
                  }}
                >
                  Delete
                </Typography.Link>
              ) : null
            ) : null}
          </>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
const mergedColumns = columns.map((col) => {
    if (!col.editable) {
      return col;
    }

    return {
      ...col,
      onCell: (record) => ({
        record,
        inputType:
          col.dataIndex === loc
            ? "number"
            : col.dataIndex === "date"
            ? "date"
            : "text",
        dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
        title: col.title,
        editing: isEditing(record),
      }),
    };
  });
  return (
    <>
      <Popconfirm title="Confirm save changes?" onConfirm={handleSubmit}>
        <Button
          key="submit"
          style={{
            marginBottom: "1em",
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "green",
          }}
        >
          Save Changes
        </Button>
      </Popconfirm>
      <Form form={form} component={false}>
        <Table
          components={{
            body: {
              cell: EditableCell,
            },
          }}
          bordered
          dataSource={data}
          columns={mergedColumns}
          rowClassName="editable-row"
          pagination={{
            onChange: cancel,
          }}
          rowKey="date"
        />
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};
}
```

**EditableCell.j**

```js
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input, InputNumber, DatePicker } from "antd";
import moment from "moment";

const EditableCell = ({
  editing,
  dataIndex,
  title,
  inputType,
  record,
  index,
  children,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const inputNode =
    inputType === "number" ? (
      <Form.Item
        style={{ margin: 0 }}
        name={dataIndex}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: `Please Input ${title}!`,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <InputNumber formatter={(value) => value} parser={(value) => value} />
      </Form.Item>
    ) : inputType === "date" ? (
      <FormItem
        style={{ margin: 0 }}
        name={dataIndex}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: `Please Input ${title}!`,
          },
        ]}
        initialValue={moment(record[dataIndex])}
      >
        <DatePicker />
      </FormItem>
    ) : (
      <Form.Item
        style={{ margin: 0 }}
        name={dataIndex}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: `Please Input ${title}!`,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    );

  return <td {...restProps}>{editing ? inputNode : children}</td>;
};

export default EditableCell;
```

**UPDATE**
Currently with the code I have, I'm getting an error where it says `date.clone is not a function`

Comment: Did u found an answer?

Comment: @HenriqueRamos No sir, I have not :(

Comment: @HenriqueRamos By any chance, have you found an answer?

Comment: No :/ i create a normal input and the user needs write a date like 10/10/2022. A regex validate the format and momentjs transform MM/DD/YYYY to ISO. @Owenn

Comment: @HenriqueRamos Aww that sucks :( But thank you so much bro!

Comment: Most likely the error occurs due to the fact that inside the data props there is a date field of type ```Date```, but there should be an instance of ```moment``` instead. Could you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Owenn checkout my solution, it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

**EditableTable.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Table, Form, Button, DatePicker } from "antd";
import moment from 'moment';

import EditableCell from "./EditableCell";

const OtherLocsTable = ({ data, setData }) => {
   const [form] = Form.useForm();
   const [editingKey, setEditingKey] = useState("");
   const isEditing = (record) => record.key === editingKey;
   const edit = (record) => {
      const {date, measurement} = record;
      form.setFieldsValue({
         date: (date) ? moment(date) : "",
         measurement: measurement || ""
      });
      setEditingKey(record.key);
   };
  const save = async (key) => {
    try {
      const row = await form.validateFields();
      const newData = [...data];
      const index = newData.findIndex((item) => key === item.key);

      if (index > -1) {
        const item = newData[index];
        newData.splice(index, 1, { ...item, ...row });
        setData(newData);
        setEditingKey("");
      } else {
        newData.push(row);
        setData(newData);
        setEditingKey("");
      }
    } catch (errInfo) {
      console.log("Validate Failed:", errInfo);
    }
  };
const columns = [
    {
      title: "Date",
      dataIndex: "date",
      key: "date",
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      title: "Measurement",
      dataIndex: "measurement",
      key: "measurement",
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      title: "Operation",
      dataIndex: "operation",
      render: (_, record) => {
        const editable = isEditing(record);
        const lastElement = [...data].pop();

        return editable ? (
          <span>
            <a
              href="javascript:;"
              onClick={() => save(record.key)}
              style={{
                marginRight: 8,
              }}
            >
              Save
            </a>
            <Popconfirm title="Sure to cancel?" onConfirm={cancel}>
              <a>Cancel</a>
            </Popconfirm>
          </span>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Typography.Link
              disabled={editingKey !== ""}
              onClick={() => edit(record)}
            >
              Edit
            </Typography.Link>
            {data.length > 1 ? (
              record.key === lastElement.key ? (
                <Typography.Link
                  type="danger"
                  disabled={editingKey !== ""}
                  onClick={() => deleteRow(record)}
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: 15,
                  }}
                >
                  Delete
                </Typography.Link>
              ) : null
            ) : null}
          </>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
const mergedColumns = columns.map((col) => {
    if (!col.editable) {
      return col;
    }

    return {
      ...col,
      onCell: (record) => ({
        record,
        inputType:
          col.dataIndex === loc
            ? "number"
            : col.dataIndex === "date"
            ? "date"
            : "text",
        dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
        title: col.title,
        editing: isEditing(record),
      }),
    };
  });
  return (
    <>
      <Popconfirm title="Confirm save changes?" onConfirm={handleSubmit}>
        <Button
          key="submit"
          style={{
            marginBottom: "1em",
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "green",
          }}
        >
          Save Changes
        </Button>
      </Popconfirm>
      <Form form={form} component={false}>
        <Table
          components={{
            body: {
              cell: EditableCell,
            },
          }}
          bordered
          dataSource={data}
          columns={mergedColumns}
          rowClassName="editable-row"
          pagination={{
            onChange: cancel,
          }}
          rowKey="date"
        />
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};
}
```

**EditableCell.j**

```react
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input, InputNumber, DatePicker } from "antd";
import moment from "moment";

const EditableCell = ({
  editing,
  dataIndex,
  title,
  inputType,
  record,
  index,
  children,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const inputNode =
    inputType === "number" ? (
      <Form.Item
        style={{ margin: 0 }}
        name={dataIndex}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: `Please Input ${title}!`,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <InputNumber formatter={(value) => value} parser={(value) => value} />
      </Form.Item>
    ) : inputType === "date" ? (
      <FormItem
        style={{ margin: 0 }}
        name={dataIndex}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: `Please Input ${title}!`,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <DatePicker formate="DD-MM-YYYY" />
      </FormItem>
    ) : (
      <Form.Item
        style={{ margin: 0 }}
        name={dataIndex}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: `Please Input ${title}!`,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    );

  return <td {...restProps}>{editing ? inputNode : children}</td>;
};

export default EditableCell;
```